# Incredibly high load average on a Centos server

Tags: linux, cassandra, centos6.4

I have a Centos 6.4 server that's being used as a Cassandra node in a production environment, it is still working and responding to queries etc, but the load average is rather "high" a.k.a. buggy? In any case, you have to see it for yourself:

[image: incredibly high load average]

Has anybody seen something like this before? Any clue on what's causing it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Adding output of cat /proc/loadavg as requested:

```
[root@vdc-08 ~]# cat /proc/loadavg
2715599674950.05 1351413955738.05 471218463336.32 1/479 8382
```

Comment: Lol, highest load avgs I ever seen.

Comment: O_o   I blame java.

Comment: @MikePurcell Indeed, although the server is still running and the numbers keep changing over time. I'm just waiting until somebody sheds some light on it before restarting the server.

Comment: Provide the output of `/proc/loadavg`

Comment: @MatthewIfe Done Matthew, thanks for taking the time to see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly a kernel bug.

This question [/proc/loadavg shows incorrect huge values](https://serverfault.com/questions/418882/proc-loadavg-shows-incorrect-huge-values) suggested updating the kernel on the host and rebooting but did not specify what the root cause is.

Comment: I'm not using cludlinux, this is a physical server running centos, but still the explanation is sound.

Comment: Did it work? Updating the kernel (with subsequent reboot)?

Answer (score 0):

this was working for me:

add "elevator=noop" in kernel boot config.

[High Load Average with modest CPU Utilization and almost no IO](https://serverfault.com/questions/482832/high-load-average-with-modest-cpu-utilization-and-almost-no-io)

Comment: "***was*** working" ... does that mean it does not anymore?